# Bootstrap Table usage questions

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table by Wenzhixin and like to know how to:

1. Display the header all the time while scrolling the table
2. Display background color alternatively

Thanks,

Comment: could you please post what you have tried so far so that you can be helped

Comment: Here is the original bt website: http://victoriaxie.com/eng/2015/9/10/a-simple-way-to-convert-csv-data-into-a-sortable-bootstraphtml-table-using-python

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your questions:

1. **Header display.** In order to display the header when scrolling (vertically), use the `height` option which will cause a scrollbar internal to the table to be displayed.
2. **Striped rows.** Use the `striped` option to achieve the alternating styling on rows.

Both of these are demonstrated in [this](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/table-style.html) bootstrap-table example.

Refer to the [bootstrap-table documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#table-options) for full details of these table options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the sticky header and alternative row-color works. However, when I have the BT in an Ajax and resize the browser, the header is misaligned. Refresh the web page make the header aligned. After searching, I got the solution at  http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/faq/      But the code is using CDN for js and css. How can my code call the local JS and CSS ?   (Sorry for this newbie question. I have spent 2 hours on it).

Comment: I'm not sure CDN is the issue; you should definitely be able to listen for the resize event and trigger resetView as per the FAQ. Do you have example code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @user3586164 have you resolved this? Did my answer help? If so, please accept.